# "Born a twin; Graduated only child" grammatical construction?

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality

I encountered this "six words story" somewhere and really puzzled over the grammatical construction of the six-word sentences. Could anyone please split the sentence and analyze its grammatical construction for me? Thanks.

Comment: It's not really particularly grammatical... at the very least, it should be *graduated **an** only child*. The format of the story is extremely rigid, so it forces poor grammar choices.

Comment: Apparently, the "six word story" idea stems from an urban legend that Hemingway once bet some friends that he could write a novel in six words.  His result: "For sale, baby shoes, never worn." won the bet.  They are presently popular, and the rules of the game allow leaving out words that are implied.  For example: "Some baby shoes, which have never been worn, are for sale." would be the unabbreviated sentence.

Comment: I'm beside myself; cloning machine works. :)

Comment: @BobRodes quite reasonable. Much thanks to your answer:)

Answer (score 3):

In order to fit into six words, a number of words are implied.  So, the sentence might read like this without the restriction:

> This person was born a twin; he graduated [as] an only child.

A person can be born with some characteristic: *born blind*, *born deaf*, *born rich*, for example.  As such, a person can be *born a twin*, meaning he was born with a twin sibling. So, the first sentence (ending with a semicolon) is saying this.  Now, much in the same way, a person can graduate with some characteristic: *graduated first in his class*, *graduated early* and so on.  You can also say that a person *graduated an only child*, but it would be more typical to add *as* to the phrase to make it clear that it is the person that is doing the graduating.  Presumably, the meaning is that the twin sibling passed away prior to the individual's graduation.

So, there are two sentences, joined by a semicolon.  *Born a twin* has an implied subject (some person).  Also, the verb *to be* is implied: *someone was* born a twin.  As for how the "twin" part is analyzed, there are two schools of thought.  One will say that *was born* is passive voice, that *born* is a "stative" verb, and that "a twin" functions as a "predicate adjective" much in the same way that *hungry* does in the sentence *I feel hungry.*  I have a bit of trouble with this, because of course *twin* is a noun.  The other point of view is that *born* is an ordinary intransitive verb, and *a twin* is a "prepositional phrase" with the preposition *as* implied.  I lean towards this explanation myself.

Now, the second sentence is pretty clearly an example of the latter analysis.  *He* is the subject, *graduated* is the verb, the verb is intransitive so there's no object, and *as an only child* is a prepositional phrase that functions as an adverb modifying the verb *graduated*.

So, in general, to make the structure clear, it's necessary to add in the implied words.